# Calling webservice method through ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have WCF service method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "validateLogin", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
[OperationContract]
bool validateLogin(Login objLogin);
```

I am calling this method through my phonegap code ajax as:

```
var parameters = {
    "EmailID": EmailID,
    "Password": Password
};

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:95/MobileEcomm/Service1.svc/validateLogin",
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    contentType: "text/xml;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: { 
        SOAPAction: '' 
    }, 
    type: 'POST',   
    processdata: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (Data) {
        alert("asdsad");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        var value = JSON.stringify(response);
        alert("Error in Saving.Please try later."+value);
    }
});
```

But service method is not getting called.

On Network tab it gives me error:

[image]

And On Console:

[image]

**EDIT1:**

When i change contenttyp to :appplication/json;charset=utf-8

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's the cause of your issue, but note that the parameter is `processData` - note the capital 'D'.

Comment: Is this service accessible if you call it via browser or postman client? Do you get a response. $.Ajax will only initiate the call but seems like there is some problem at service end. Moreover, did you see if you are sending all the parameters properly if required by your service

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ohh thanks...but only one error from console got removed by this (Failed to load...) ... POST error is still there

Comment: @Vatsal if i call url from browser like : http://localhost:95/MobileEcomm/Service1.svc/validateLogin?EmailID='whatever@yahoo.com'&Password='whatever'   It works... but not getting called through ajax

Comment: `RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml` and `contentType: "text/xml;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "xml"` look pretty strange when you do `data: JSON.stringify(parameters)`

Comment: @MotiAzu I made both the things json, but still the problem is same

Comment: @CuteChild What about the content and data type?

Comment: @Priyesh I changed it to json...but problem is same

Comment: @CuteChild Click the failed request in the network tab and give us the details of the failure.

Comment: @CuteChild Why do you call `JSON.stringify()` when you web service is accepting json as a request? Your `parameters` variable is already a JSON...

Comment: @Kutyel `parameters` is a js reference, not a raw json string

Comment: @MotiAzu should i remove json stringify???

Comment: @CuteChild Nope, he's ok. But the cross domain may be your pitfall, can you check if the server encountered any requests? did the browser block it or did it just fail on the server? Also - change the content type to `application/json`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `dataType` to `jsonp` rather than using `json`?

Comment: @scheien yes i tried it. But same error

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

crossDomain point in doc

Check it, u send cross domain ajax. It's not allowed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because of Parameters which you are passing and return type of WCF service. The method should return Object instead of `bool`. The .Net framework will convert the returned object to the JSON string automatically for you.

**Service Side :**

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "validateLogin", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    [OperationContract]
    Object validateLogin(String Email, String Password)
        {
           //Do your stuff return bool value
        }
```

**AJAX Call :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:95/MobileEcomm/Service1.svc/validateLogin",
    data: function ( {
              return JSON.stringify({
                Email: "abc@xyz.com",
                Password: "XXXXXXXXXX"
               });
             },
    contentType: "text/xml;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: { 
        SOAPAction: '' 
    }, 
    type: 'POST',   
    processdata: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (Data) {
        alert("asdsad");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        var value = JSON.stringify(response);
        alert("Error in Saving.Please try later."+value);
    }
});
```