# Ajax not invoking service method through phonegap

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have ajax call as:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:95/MobileEcomm/Service1.svc/validateLogin",
        crossDomain: true,
        data:{ 'EmailID':EmailID, 'Password':Password},
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
            // do something with server response data
        },
        error: function (err) {
            // handle your error logic here
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

I wanted to invoke:

```
[WebInvoke(
  Method = "POST",
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  UriTemplate = "validateLogin/{Email}/{Password}")]
        [OperationContract]
        string validateLogin(string Email, string Password);
```

But i always go into error block of ajax.

What is mistake in my ajax call?

Error1:

[image]

Error 2 :

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that phonegap app can access your localhost:95 server?

Comment: yes, its plain html code @VsevolodGoloviznin

Comment: @CuteChild what I mean is that usually the localhost environment is not accessible via network

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I have hosted service in IIS

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I posted the errors

Comment: data:{ 'EmailID':EmailID, 'Password':Password} its better you use  data:{ 'Email':EmailID, 'Password':Password} as you are using Email in your URI

Comment: try adding application/json into your header

Comment: @RamzanZafar but what is the difference between two things you posted?

Comment: @CuteChild that change was use Email instead of EmailID

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling webservice method through ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015750/calling-webservice-method-through-ajax)

Comment: you should add contentType: 'application/json'\

Comment: Apparently using some kind of emulator and obscure tooling chain, as he mentioned on the C# chat room. No clue what is it and he is completely reluctant to add information; hence, -1 vote, for incomplete information, unclear question, unclear error, and unclear tooling.

Answer (score 1):

1) There are many difficult-to-catch errors when the app is running some or all of its files on `file://` protocol. It's recommended to debug your apps entirely on `http://`. If all URIs with `file://` protocol are related to Ripple emulator, see next point.

2) There is a restriction named [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (CORS). As your app seems to run on `localhost:58889` and the called server resides on `localhost:95`, these two are considered *different* servers. Ripple emulator has some sort of proxy to bypass CORS, try turn it on. I was using also [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) with Ripple emulator successfully in the past.

Note: *Status: Failed* and *Type: Pending* does not belong to contentType mismatch, but 99% it's CORS problem.

Comment: Chrome developer tools window title. It's either server of your app or Ripple's server and there are answers to both of it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding contentType into your call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:95/MobileEcomm/Service1.svc/validateLogin",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:{ 'EmailID':EmailID, 'Password':Password},
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
            // do something with server response data
        },
        error: function (err) {
            // handle your error logic here
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```